# Optimize MySQL Query (Slow)

Tags: mysql

Someone can help me to optimize the following MySQL query?

```
SELECT SUM(ROUND(rp.distance,2)), t.name, MONTH(tr.assigned)
FROM tab1 tr
JOIN tab2 rp ON rp.robot=tr.robot 
JOIN tab3 t ON t.idTask=tr.idTask
GROUP BY t.name, MONTH(tr.assigned)
```

The query takes 20 seconds to execute. Without the GROUP BY down to 10 seconds. I tested with DISTINCT but I failed to improve the time. Any ideas?

Comment: pls show explain results

Comment: id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1  SIMPLE  tr  ALL  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  6564  Using temporary; Using filesort
1  SIMPLE  t  eq_ref  PRIMARY  PRIMARY  4  testdb.tr.idTask  1  (NULL)
1  SIMPLE  rp  ALL  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  10943  Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)

Comment: You can edit that into the question.

Comment: your query is not using proper index, so create index on rp.robot, tr.robot, t.idtask, tr.idtask fields...and then try.

Comment: Thank you Zafar. I'm going to test it.

Comment: Zafar, I already had those fields as index ...

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
SELECT SUM(distance), t.name, MONTH(tr.assigned)
FROM tab1 tr
JOIN tab2 rp ON rp.robot=tr.robot 
JOIN (select ROUND(rp.distance,2) as distance, a.idTask from tab3 a) t ON t.idTask=tr.idTask
GROUP BY t.name, MONTH(tr.assigned)
```

Comment: Shows me an error: "Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'rp.distance' in 'field list'"

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT SUM(ROUND(rp.distance, 2)), t.name, MONTH(tr.assigned)
FROM tab1 tr JOIN
     tab2 rp
     ON rp.robot = tr.robot JOIN
     tab3 t
     ON t.idTask = tr.idTask
GROUP BY t.name, MONTH(tr.assigned);
```

It looks reasonable.  So, before radically rewriting it, do you have the following indexes:  `tab1(robot, idtask, assigned)`, `tbl2(robot)`, and `tab3(idtask, name)`.

Next, perhaps the volume of data is just too big.  MySQL is pretty bad when it comes to `group by` -- and 10 seconds for a `group by` suggests a lot of data.  Is there any way you can reduce the size of the data?  What are the sizes of the tables?  How large is the result set?

If you have lots of data, then 20 seconds may not be unreasonable.

Comment: I can't reduce the size. I'm going to test make the index in rows robot, idTask, etc

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are grouping by string, so you need to add index on `name` column. You have to always use indexes when joining MySQL tables

Comment: I tried to add name as an index but is taking 20 seconds too. Anyway thank you very much for the help.